# Snowflake SQL execution canceled in .NET while running update query in Parallel.ForEach

Tags: .net, parallel-processing, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am performing update operation in the snowflake using .NET connector. For parallel execution of update operation, I am using `Parallel.Foreach()` but it throws "SQL execution canceled"

Following is the code

```cs
// I have list of items call it "items"

// Open the snowflake connection

var cmd = (SnowflakeDbCommand)conn.CreateCommand();

Parallel.ForEach( items, i => {
    cmd.CommandText = "update query";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
});

// close the connection
```

After running the code, logs in snowflake shows "SQL execution canceled".

If I perform update in simple for loop, it takes forever to update million rows. Is there any another way to perform this task?

Comment: Have you tried awaiting `cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` call? I.e., `await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);`. You might want to make your method `async`, though (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)).

Comment: Yeah, I have tried that, but no success.

Comment: Also, make sure your method does not return `void`; `async` and `await` won't work as expected when your method returns `void`. Can you post the method signature here too?